# Ho do I get max and min values from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string that looks something like this:

```
£25 - £30More than £30£20 - £25£20 - £25, More than £30, £25 - £30, £15 - £20, Up to £15£15 - £20
```

ie, it is several ranges put together in a random order, possible with or without whitespace or comma breaks.

I want to get the largest and smallest values from it.  How do I do that efficiently?  I am certain there will be a simple regex but I cannot see it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex could help:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = '£25 - £30More than £30£20 - £25£20 - £25, More than £30, £25 - £30, £15 - £20, Up to £15£15 - £20'
>>> max(map(int, re.findall('\d+', string)))
30
>>>
```

**Edit:**

If you have value with commas, like `3,000`, try:

```
>>> max(map(lambda x: int(x.replace(',', '')), re.findall('[\d+,]+', string)))
3000
```

Comment: thank you.  I just realised the values could also have commas in the, like this `£1,750 - £2,000£1,250 - £1,500£1,500 - £1,750More than £2,000£1,000 - £1,250Up to £750, £750 - £1,000`  How would it change?

Comment: Wouldn't "more than 30" be a larger maximum value?

Comment: @HenryM The edit part would work for all numbers with comma

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import numpy as np
np.max([int(x) for x in re.split(r'\D','£25 - £30More than £30£20 - £25£20 - £25, More than £30, £25 - £30, £15 - £20, Up to £15£15 - £20') if len(x) > 0])
```

Comment: You don't have to `import numpy`. You can just use `max` from the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
values =  '£25 - £30More than £30£20 - £25£20 - £25, More than £30, £25 - £30, £15 - £20, Up to £15£15 - £20'
int_values = [int(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d+',values)]
print(min(int_values))
print(max(int_values))
```

output

```
15
30
```

Comment: Isn't this almost the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69103455/9857631) answer?

Comment: @not_speshal not really . `numpy` is not in use. The solution does not require any external lib